# Shift between WMS Tiles in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, wms, tiles

I use Leaflet to show a WMS Layer via a proxy.php (for authentication). That is working on most WMS Layers. But I have some WMS Sources, which are having a small shift in the tiles. See Overlay Map in the example.

[image: Shift between WMS Tiles in Leaflet]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

TEST MAP

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
```

```
var map1  = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 30,
    maxNativeZoom: 18
});


var map4 = new L.tileLayer.wms("proxy.php?url=http://geoshop.kommunalportal.ch/SWMS?", {
    layers: 'lk_wms_wasser',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    maxZoom:30
});

var map = L.map('mapid').setView([47.549904, 9.152927], 18);

var baseMaps = {
    "map1": map1
    
};

var overlayMaps = {
    "map4": map4
};

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);

map1.addTo(map);
map4.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: what projection is your WMTS layer in?

Comment: I updated the question with code. So the Projection is standard from Leaflet. You can see the code in Action at: [link](https://entwicklung.firetab.ch/maptest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard projection for Leaflet is `EPSG:3857`. If you submit `GetCapabilites` request to you WMS server, you'll see that it supports only the following projections: `EPSG:2056` and `EPSG:21781`.

This means two things:

1. If you want to use this layer, you'll have to define on of those projections with `proj4leaflet` plugin and then use it for your layer and your map.
2. Since Leaflet supports only one projection per map, you will not be able to combine this layer with OpenStreet layer, which has only `EPSG:3857` projection.

Comment: Thank's, you helped me a lot! I could manage it using proj4leaflet